# How I could use jlabel with setbounds in oneline without use a extra variable in jpanel?

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel

I have my code for use setbound but this use 3 lines  without use hellolabel variable

```
JLabel helloLabel = new JLabel("Hello world!");
helloLabel.setBounds( 10, 50, 60, 20 );  
panel.add(helloLabel);
```

How i could do this but using a style of oneline like this

```
paintPane.add((new JLabel("Hello world!")).setBounds( 10, 50, 60, 20 ));
```

I use this but appear "void' type not allowed here".

Comment: Don't use `setBounds()`.  Use a layout manager.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need use coordinates  x;y for my task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to create my own method which create a Labels like this :

```
public JLabel createLabel(String title, Rectangle bounds){
    JLabel label = new JLabel(title);
    label.setBounds(bounds);
    return label;
}
```

so you can use your method in one line :

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.add(createLabel("Hello world!", new Rectangle(10, 50, 60, 20)));
```